# Why did `show cluster details` returned `INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR(305)` error when upgrading Apache IoTDB Version from 1.0.1 to 1.2?

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to upgrade Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.1 to Version 1.2. After replacing the `lib` files, I can successfully startup IoTDB, but when executing `show cluster details` command, an error is reported: `ERROR o.a.i.d.u.ErrorHandlingUtils:61 - Status code: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR(305), operation: "show cluster details" . executeStatement failed`. In my upgrading process, I first executed `sh stop-stand-alone.sh`, then replaced `lib` files and executed `sh start-stand-alone.sh`, so all the ConfigNodes should be stopped when upgrading. Therefore, anyone knows why the IoTDB cluster execution went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to upgrade from Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.X to Version 1.1 first, and then to Version 1.2. The upgrading way from 1.0.X to 1.1 is the same way you mentioned, by changing `lib` files. See if in this way your problem will be solved.